# C++ string wont output value properly

Tags: c++

The goal of this program is to  create a function (combineStr) that concatenates a string by a number of times.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

string combineStr(string input, int times) {
    string output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
        output += times;
    }
    return output;
}

int main(){
    string input;
    int times;
    cout << "Enter a string: ";
    cin >> input;

    cout << "Enter a number of times: ";
    cin >> times;
    if(times == 0){
        return 0;
    }

    string output = combineStr(input,times);

    cout << "The resulting string is: " << output << endl;
}
```

For some reason when I compile and run the program, it simply outputs "The resulting string is: " without the repeated string. Help?

Comment: you are adding integer to string variable, i think that is the issue. `output += times;` you should write `output += input;`

Comment: why is this getting upvoted, geez. Typo questions are off-topic here. You should've used a debugger.

Comment: It is the issue. Output will contain non printable character 0x05 five times if times  is five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the statement inside loop.

> output += times; to  output += input;

```
string combineStr(string input, int times) {
    string output = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < times; i++){
       output += input;
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG I'm so stupid... haha thank you for pointing that out. *facepalms*

Comment: @CalebMoriarty minor mistake. it happens with everybody. cheers.